# Tabla supera las dimensiones de la pagina HTML

Tags: html, css

Cordial saludo.
Actualmente en mi sitio web, tengo una tabla que tiene 28 columnas y 102 filas.
Las 28 columnas se puede visualizar utilizando la barra horizontal de la parte inferior, pero de las 102 filas, solo puedo ver 33 al utilizar la barra vertical del lado derecho.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para poder visualizar las 102 filas utilizando la barra vertical del lado derecho?

Gracias

Comment: Te sugiero que pongas el código de css y el del html también aclara si usas algún framework(css) o no y edita tu pregunta

Comment: Hola, muéstranos tu código para revisar si hay algo por ahí en el CSS que limite el contenido del DOM. Sin Código no podemos adivinar. [Pásate por esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que conozcas como preguntar y evitar que te cierren la pregunta.

Comment: e tratado de poner el codigo pero me sale esto: Parece que tu publicación es mayormente código; por favor, añade más detalles. Que debo hacer para poderlo poner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordial saludo. Ya encontré la limitante que no me permitía ver la totalidad de los datos en la pagina web. En la consulta SQL SERVER que hago, me traigo un campo cuyos registros tienen mas de 2206 caracteres. Note que una vez la consulta encuentra un dato que supera ese limite, no es mostrada en la pagina. Solo muestras los campos cuyos registros son inferior a 2141 caracteres.
Teniendo lo anterior presente, fui a la consulta en SQL SERVER y quite ese campo, pues realmente no lo estaba mostrando, pero el tenerlo, interrumpía los datos que si quiera mostrar.

Espero esto le sea de utilidad a otras personas.